# How To Chart ANY Token on TradingView?

Tags: charts, token, cryptocurrency, tradingview-api, binance-smart-chain

Using WBNB as an example (0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c), where would I find the data to chart the token using TradingView lightweight charting library? Also, can this be achieved on the testnet as well?